# After HDP cluster kerberized Journal node service having issue while starting

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

Below is the error after cluster kerberized.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Login failure for jn/keystone.mwbsys.com@EXAMPLE.COM from keytab /etc/security/keytabs/jn.service.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

Answer (score 0):

added keystone.mwbsys.com in /etc/hosts file

and then restarted the journal nodes its fixed the issue. I know this is not the permenent solution but it worked.